# How can force web browser to render Ajax response, which is whole html page?

Tags: javascript, html

The aim is, when receive Ajax response to force browser to render "responseText" like is loaded new html page. Add "responseText" to "innerHTML" of document not force browser to reflow the page with new added markup.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
  <head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>START BOOTSRAP 4</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <h1>BOOTSTRAP 4 NAV</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="horizontal-line"></div>
    <p>The <kbd>.nav</kbd>, <kbd>.nav-item</kbd>, <kbd>.nav-link</kbd> classes:</p>
    <ul class="nav">
        <div class="nav-item">
         <a href="#" class="nav-link">Nav-Link-1</a>
       </div>
    </ul>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

var html;

xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
   if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

      html = this.responseText;

     // how to apply this 'html' that to see rendered web page
     // with css styles etc.

  }
};

    // ---- Not working in this case... only for example ----
    // var win = window.open("", "_self");
   // win.document.open();
   // win.document.write(html);
   // win.document.close();
  // ---- End of Not working in this case... only for example ----

xhttp.open("GET", "http://127.0.0.1/nav.html", true);

xhttp.send();
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Why don't you use an iFrame?

Comment: Why wouldn't you just load the new page completely using normal link process?

Comment: 1. For example with : iframe = "<iframe width='100%' height='100%' src='" + html + "'></iframe>" again not working.
2. Not using normal link process, because of test purposes.
Thanks !

Comment: That's not how iframes work, The src attribute is for a url src to a file

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** If you need to load external CSS/JS or dynamically run scripts on the page, the vanilla JS below will not do. Since you are using jQuery, you can achieve this with jQuery's `html` function to replace the html of the entire page, while loading external files and executing scripts:

```
$("html").html(html);
```

**Edit:** Solution below using vanilla JS only applies for simple cases that don't rely on script execution or external files.

Once you have the html from the ajax response, grab the `html` element using `getElementsByTagName`, and set its `innerHTML` property to the received HTML:

```
document.querySelector("html").innerHTML = html;
```

If you just need to replace the body of the page, grab the `body` element and set its `innerHTML` property to the received HTML:

```
document.body.innerHTML = html;
```

Comment: Can't nest new `<html>` , `<head>` and `<body>` inside existing `<body>`

Comment: @charlietfl if the response includes `<html>`, `<head>`, or `<body>` then you would use the first approach shown above, which replaces the entire html contents of the page.

Comment: Don’t use ‘getElementsByTagName()’ when you just want one element. Use ‘querySelector()’ for that. And, to get the body, just use ‘document.body’.

Comment: @ScottMarcus agree with you on `document.body` (edited answer), but I think `querySelector` is overkill for grabbing `<html>` -- it's the perfect use case for `getElementsByTagName`.

Comment: I don’t think you understand what ‘.getElementsByTagName()’ does. It is actually the perfect example of how not to scan the DOM in this case. You’ve got it exactly backwards. ‘querySelector()’ here is exponentially more efficient.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. I do have it backwards -- I'll make that edit. Thanks!

Comment: But then OP expects all the scripts and css files to load too. Basically a clean new page using ajax. Whole idea is not really well thought out by OP

Comment: Good point. Looks like we'll have to use jQuery to achieve what we need. Edited answer to reflect this

Comment: ?? JQuery is not a requirement for this, or any problem. JQuery is JavaScript.

Comment: I should be more careful with my phrasing. What I meant to say was that while we don't *need* jQuery, OP is already using jQuery on his application, so why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: almost perfect, but it is not applying the styles from CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at jQuery .load()

```
$("#idToAppendTo").load("your.html");
```

Here's a link http://api.jquery.com/load/

Alternatively, once you have the html via your ajax request use this

```
document.getElementById("#idToAppendTo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
```